# Python: Same workload divided across 4 cores works with multiprocessing library but hangs when using mpi4py

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi

I'm trying to learn more about multiprocessing using Python. So far I have used the multiprocessing library and the mpi4py library, trying to solve quite a simple problem. Adding a large amount of numbers.

I used the following logic, the goal was to add all numbers up to 10^8 so i divided this range into 4 (the number of cores my laptop has) equal ranges, split the load across all cores and then added the results together on one core.

Here are the two different approaches I have so far.

Using the multiprocessing library:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time

def sum_nums(low, high):
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(low, high+1):
        result += i
    return result

def sn((low,high)):
    return sum_nums(low, high) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    p = Pool(4)

    n = int(1e8)
    r = range(0,10**8+1,n)
    results = []

    t = time()
    for arg in zip([x+1 for x in r],r[1:]):
        results.append(p.apply_async(sum_nums, arg))

    # wait for results
    print sum(res.get() for res in results)
    print '{} s'.format(time() -t)
```

Using the mpi4py library:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    end = 10**9
    step = round((end+1)/size)
    limits = np.linspace(start=0, stop=end,num=size+1, 
endpoint=True, dtype=int)
    space = []
    for arg in zip([x+1 for x in limits],limits[1:]):
        space.append(arg)
else:
    space = None

data = comm.scatter(space, root=0)
start = time.time()
res = np.sum(np.arange(start=data[0], stop=data[1]+1))

timeDiff = time.time() - start
results = comm.gather(res, root=0)
totalTime = comm.gather(timeDiff, root=0)
if rank == 0:
    end = time.time()
    print(sum(results))
    print("Average computing time: {:.3f}s".format(sum(totalTime)/size))
```

The thing is, that while the mpi4py library runs much faster, trying to calculate the sum up to 10^7 it takes close to 1 second, while using the first code it takes up to 4. When trying to solve for 10^8 the second code hangs, while the first gives results in about 15 seconds.

Why does this happen? Is it a memory issue? Have I gotten something completely wrong in the second code?

The first code is written in python 2.7.15 and the second in python 3.6.7.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any answer is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a memory issue.
I've tried the second code in my python 3.6.7 environment. The code works on my computer when end<=10^9. More than 40GB memory was needed on my computer, when end up to 10^10.